# Surrounding a Scanner with try-with-resources

Tags: java, file, netbeans, input

I've created a an algorithm to read in a file and check multiple questions of user input. I am using Netbeans, and it is suggesting a try-with-resources. What I'm not sure about is the closing of the file. When I first created my algorithm, I put the file.close() in the wrong spot, as it couldn't be reached because there was a "return" statement before it:

```
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        String word = inputFile.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < sentance.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < punc.length; j++) {
                if (sentance[i].equalsIgnoreCase(word + punc[j])) {

                    return "I am a newborn. Not even a year old yet.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    inputFile.close(); // Problem
```

So i fixed it with this:

```
        File file = new File("src/res/AgeQs.dat");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        String word = inputFile.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < sentance.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < punc.length; j++) {
                if (sentance[i].equalsIgnoreCase(word + punc[j])) {
                    inputFile.close(); // Problem fixed
                    return "I am a newborn. Not even a year old yet.";
                }
            }
        }  
    }
```

The question is, when I had set it up the wrong way, Netbeans suggested this:

```
        File file = new File("src/res/AgeQs.dat");
    try (Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            String word = inputFile.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < sentance.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < punc.length; j++) {
                    if (sentance[i].equalsIgnoreCase(word + punc[j])) {

                        return "I am a newborn. Not even a year old yet.";
                    }
                }
            }  
        }
    }
```

is Netbeans correcting my code, or just removing the closing of the file? Is this a better way to go about doing this? I don't like to use code unless I know exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 6):

try-with-resources provides a guarantee that AutoCloseable resources, like Scanner, will  always be closed. Closing is added implicitly by javac approx. as

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
try {
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        ....
    }
} finally {
    inputFile.close();
}
```

BTW there is a problem in your code that Netbeans failed to notice. Scanner's methods do not throw IOException but supppress it. Use Scanner.ioException to check if any exception occurred during reading file.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), re Java 7's try-with-resource block.

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

Java 6 doesn't support try-with-resources; you must explicitly close the IO stream.

Answer (score 1):

> is Netbeans correcting my code, or just removing the closing of the file?

It is correcting your code.  The try-with-resource has in implicit finally clause that closes the resources that were declared / created in the resource section.  (All resources must implement the `Closeable` interface ...)